# How does Rails import existing rows when you "Edit" in scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, scaffolding

That was probably a very badly worded question, but I'm curious how Rails knows to bring in the form data when you click edit. For example, if I scaffolded a model called Post, and typed in a title and content for that Post, later when I edit it, the form is automatically filled in.

I looked at the controller and the form partial, but it doesn't seem like it contains anything to tell it to fill it up with the existing data.

The reason I am asking this is because I want to allow users to "import" other people's posts into their form and edit it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, start by looking at the link to edit your model - in the index view file (`app/views/posts/index.html.erb`) it will look like:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
```

When you open the index page in your browser, this builds a link like:

```
http://*servername*/post/*id*/edit
```

The resource routing knows that this calls the `edit` action of the `post_controller`, and that the `id` value is in the URL.

Now take a look at the `edit` action in your `post_controller` (`app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`) - it looks like:

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

all this does is use the `id` value that was passed through the URL to find the `Post` in the database with that `id`, and save it in the variable `@post`.
If you look in the code of the edit view file (`app/views/posts/edit.html.erb`) it mostly just uses the form partial (`/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb`) and that file contains the code for rendering the actual form you see in the browser.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
```

This line starts building the form using the `@post` variable that got set in the `PostsController` `edit` action.  Inside the block for this code, you see things like -

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
```

This code builds a text field in the form tied to the `:title` property of `@post` - if a value exists in that property, the `text_field` method knows to populate the text field with that value.

The second part ('I want to allow users to "import" other people's posts into their form and edit it') is a lot more open-ended and depends more on what you actually want to do in your app - you could just allow all users to see all other users posts and edit them directly (kind of like a wiki, but with destructive edits). Or you could make posts editable only by the user that created them, but viewable by others, and then you could create a controller action that allows a user to copy the contents of another user's post into a new post owned by the current user. Or other things - it really just depends what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I guess '<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>' was the part I was looking for!

Comment: For the second part, I want to make the posts copyable, and then have other users insert another row (even though it might be the same data, I want to open it up to the possibility of both of them changing). I already created a Folder mission, so users can collect these posts, and then I want them to be able to import the collected Posts. Would I just find the collected Posts in the controller through params, and then use the form_for(@whatever) ?

Comment: So if I wanted to essentially make a copy of someone else's post, how would i do this, since form_for(@xxxx) will change the original post. i supposed i could just create another row with the same params and have the author edit tht, but i dont want to clog up the db until they actually 'submit' the new version

Comment: What you would do to make a copy is look up the original (original = Post.find()), then you would create a new Post (@post = Post.new), then you would copy values (@post.title = original.title, etc.), now in your view, @post refers to the new copied Post.  Creating a Post via new() doesn't create a record in the database, if you create the Post via create() it will (create() is like calling new() and then save()).

Answer (score 2):

In case of an edit, the controller get an object with the id of the item you want to edit. As the item is an instance variable that is available to the view and the [form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), that are used in the view, generate HTML that gives the HTML field the value that is shown inside them. Rails Form Helper magic I should say ! (well if you write plain HTML then is it as simple as doing `<input value="<%= @post.title %>`" this is what the Rails helper does for you automatically when you use `f.text_field :title`)

Importing other people's posts is kind of a business logic that I am not sure how your application would implement. But if a user clicks on a Edit Link for a post, then in the view that is populated he should see the existing values already populated in the form.